# How to Distribute Soil moisture output of Thornthwaite and Mather (1954) Soil Water Balance Model into different layers?

Tags: water, soil, climatology, soil-science, soil-moisture

in `Thornthwaite & Mather (1954) Soil Water Balance Approach`
The soil moisture output is generated for the whole soil profile, i.e whatever depth we take for the model eg: `from surface to 60 cm`  or  `from surface to 100 cm`

The basic approach is,
for any time scale,

1. if precipitation is more than the potential evapotranspiration then, the net/balance moisture is added to the previous/initial moisture of previous time step (day/month etc.)
2. if potential evapotranspiration exceeds precipitation or there is no precipitation at all, then soil moisture for the current time step will decrease exponentially from the soil moisture available in the previous time step following the empirical equation mentioned in the flowchart.

The reference publications are available at:- [reference 1](http://www.hydrology.bee.cornell.edu/BEE3710Handouts/TM2013.pdf), [reference 2](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1623/hysj.49.1.131.53997), [reference 3](https://eujournal.org/index.php/esj/article/view/8526), [reference 4](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10661-019-7230-9)

[image: Flowchart]

The output generated by the model follows the trend corresponding to precipitation, runoff and ET that happened during the subsequent time period.
[image: SM out]

But is there any way to distribute this output into different layers,

say, we run the model for 100 cm soil profile (surface to 100 cm soil depth), and got the output values at each day/month.
How can we distribute it to different layers say from 0-15, 15-30, 30-60, and 60-100cm.

What I did here was, that I saturate the 1st layer (0-15cm), then sent the residual moisture to the bottom layers, then saturated the 2nd layer (15-30cm) and sent the residual moisture again to the layers below, and so on....

but results are logically not right, the top layers always stay saturated and the bottom layers always remain dry.
[image: Layered SM]

However the soil moisture from the top layers should deplete first, as the evapotranspirational losses from top layers will be more as compared to the bottom layers, and the moisture in the bottom layers should be more stable.

another thing here is that Thornthwaite soil water balance model uses `available water capacity` in its equations
i.e the water held in the soil between `field capacity` and `permanent wilting point`,
but the `saturation limit` of soil is above `field capacity`
so saturating the layer using `saturation limit` in spite of `field capacity` also does not seems ideal here.

**So how this soil moisture generated from Thornthwaite & Mather (1954) Soil Water Balance Model can be distributed into different layers.**
Suggestions will be highly appreciated.